# How to make a loop with 3 variables and to export files

Tags: matlab, loops, variables, export

I have been trying to make a loop for 3 variables that must add 1 to each other, but these variables must change in intervals of 0.1, as long as, they do not exceed the sum of 1.

In addition, I have also been trying to make another loop to export each combination of the variables in a separate CSV file.
I have tried several ways, but to no success..

It would be very helpful if you could solve it. Thanks

```
function f = MultipleMax(w,mu,sigma)   
sum = 0;
zero = 1e-9;
n = length(w);
for i=1:length(w)
    if w(i) > zero 
        sum = sum - w(i) * log(w(i));
    end
end
f(1) = -(x)*(w * mu') + (y)*(sqrt(w*sigma*w')) + (z)*exp(sum) ;      
end
```

As you can see in the **f(1)**, the 3 variables are **x, y, and z**, then they must add 1. So, I need to create a loop that combines each of these variables in changes of 0.1 each.

the other part of my problem is that, I export the tables with this code, **T** is the name of the table:

```
writetable(T,'Nombre.csv');
```

Then, for each combination that I loop the variables above, I must export a file from each table. But I have not had any results with the functions I use.

If you have any answer it would be of great help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you're looking for something like this.

```
for x = 0:0.1:1
    for y = 0:0.1:1
        z = 1-x-y
        ...
    end
end
```

Regarding the file name, it sounds like you need a separate file for each combination of `x,y,z`. One way to achieve this is to include the values of `x,y,z` as part of the file name. For instance:

```
writetable(T,sprintf('Nombre-x-%.1f-y-%.1f.csv',x,y))
```

This includes the values of x and y as part of the file name. To find z, use the fact that x+y+z=1.